# How to put error lines in manually in barplot?

Tags: r, text, plot, error-handling, bar-chart

I have now tried to fix manually create error bars into my barplot? Is that possible and if yes, how do I do that? Furthermore, is it possible and how do I add text between to plots for showing significance levels? (such as [Barplot with significant differences and interactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535708/barplot-with-significant-differences-and-interactions))

I would appreciate any kind of help!

My code look like this:

```
pdf(file="barplo1.pdf",  title="WHAT TITLE HERE?", pointsize=6, width=4, height=4, paper="special")
par(mfrow = c(3, 2), oma=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), mar=c(2,5,2,2))
barplot(c(36.5,49.8), names.arg = c("Low", "High"), beside = TRUE, ylab = "", main="Power", col = c("grey", "gray50"), ylim = c(0,100), cex.lab=1.7, cex.axis = 1.4, cex.names = 1.4, cex.main = 1.8, lwd = 0.5, border = NA)
text(0.71,39.5, "36,5 pct.***", pos=3, cex= 1.4)
text(1.9,52.8, "49,8 pct.***", pos=3, cex= 1.4)
barplot(c(39.5,50.6), names.arg = c("Low", "High"), beside = TRUE, main="", col = c("grey", "gray50"), ylim = c(0,100), cex.axis = 1.4, cex.names = 1.4, cex.main = 1.8, lwd = 0.5, border = NA)
text(0.71,42.5, "39,5 pct.***", pos=3, cex= 1.4)
text(1.9,53.6, "50,6 pct.***", pos=3, cex= 1.4)
barplot(c(33.5,50.1), names.arg = c("Low", "High"), beside = TRUE, ylab = "", col = c("grey", "gray50"), ylim = c(0,100), cex.lab=1.7, cex.axis = 1.4, cex.names = 1.4, lwd = 0.5, border = NA)
text(0.71,36.5, "33,5 pct.***", pos=3, cex= 1.4)
text(1.9,53.1, "50,1 pct.***", pos=3, cex= 1.4)
barplot(c(49.5,61.5), names.arg = c("Low", "High"), beside = TRUE, col = c("grey", "gray50"), ylim = c(0,100), cex.axis = 1.4, cex.names = 1.4, lwd = 0.5, border = NA)
text(0.71,52.5, "49,5 pct.***", pos=3, cex= 1.4)
text(1.9,64.5, "61,5 pct.***", pos=3, cex= 1.4)
barplot(c(40.0,48.5), names.arg = c("Low", "High"), beside = TRUE,  col = c("grey", "gray50"), ylim = c(0,100), ylab = "", cex.lab=1.7, cex.axis = 1.4, cex.names = 1.4, lwd = 0.5, border = NA)
text(0.71,43.0, "40,0 pct.***", pos=3, cex= 1.4)
text(1.9,51.5, "48,5 pct.***", pos=3, cex= 1.4)
barplot(c(45.5,70.2), names.arg = c("Low", "High"), beside = TRUE, col = c("grey", "gray50"), ylim = c(0,100), cex.axis = 1.4, cex.names = 1.4, lwd = 0.5, border = NA)
text(0.71,48.5, "45,5 pct.***", pos=3, cex= 1.4)
text(1.9,73.2, "70,2 pct.***", pos=3, cex= 1.4)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need to run each call to `barplot()` twice, once to get a vector with the x coordinates at the midpoint of each bar to be drawn and then a second time to make the plot. Then, after making the plot, you can use `segments()` to add a line representing the CI in the middle of each bar. Here's a simple example:

```
x <- c(4, 3, 7)
z <- barplot(x, plot=FALSE)  # This returns a vector with the x-axis midpoints of the bars it would have drawn; they are *not* integers, which is why this is tricky
png("barplot.with.cis.png", width=5, height=5, unit="in", res=150)
par(mai=c(0.5,0.5,0.1,0.1))
barplot(x)
segments(x0=z, x1=z, y0=x-1, y1=x+1)
dev.off()
```

That produces this plot:

[image]

In your case, you'd want to plug the lower and upper bounds of your CIs in as your y0 and y1 vectors in your call to `segments()`. You can also use that `z` vector as the x coordinates for your text annotations; the corresponding values will be your y coordinates.

Finally, notice that you need to set the `ylim` in the call to `barplot(x)` to leave room for the CIs to come. You could also key that off of your CI's upper bounds with something like `ylim=c(0, ceiling(max([vector of CI upper bounds])))`.